# AngularJS "caching" on slow internet connection :(

Tags: angularjs, caching, web-applications, coffeescript

I've a simple angularjs application like:

```
module = angular.module 'testFooBarModule', ['ngResource']

module.factory 'FooBar', ($resource)->
    $resource 'foobar/target', {},
        load:
            method: 'GET'
            cache: false # no effect
            headers: 
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' # no effect

module.controller 'FooBarCtrl', ($scope, FooBar)->
    FooBar.load (result)->
        console.log result
```

With highspeed internet like home wlan or mobile hspa everything works fine. The request has fired and the server gives me a unique response. 
But with 2G internet like edge or gprs the server receives no requests and the angularjs app give me always the same results. No errors occur. The "no-cache" header were sended as well.

I've no idea what's wrong. Can anyone help me?

Sry for my english :D

best regards.

Comment: So far I've seen others solving this problem by adding a dynamic param (such as timestamp) to GET request, to simulate new request. Haven't seen usage of no-cache in such case.

Comment: also you can  play with angular promises to cache data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats probably not an angular issue. My guess is the internet-provider is doing some magic http-proxying to safe bandwidth or your underlying OS is trying to cache it for you.

Some options:

- using HTTPS should prevent provider man-in-the-middles and for mobile apps in any case a good idea!
- using a clumsy dynamic parameter like a timestamp
- use POST or PUT as verbs
- add the 'Cache-Control: no-cache' header in the server-response, which I think the is the most-clean solution